# (*vm)->GetEnv segfaults only on HTC devices

Tags: android, segmentation-fault, java-native-interface

Im currently working on a bigger project with multiple threads in the native environment. Therefore I need a call to (*vm)->GetEnv to receive the currently active JNIEnv for the native thread. The threads are attached on creation but I added a fail-over in the method which calls GetEnv:

```
void get_jni_env(void **e) {
    JNIEnv *env = malloc(sizeof(JNIEnv *));

    if((*vm)->GetEnv(vm, (void **)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_4) != JNI_OK) {
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Call to GetEnv from a unattached native thread. Trying to attach thread.");
        if((*vm)->AttachCurrentThread(vm, &env, NULL) != JNI_OK) {
            __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Failed to receive any jni environment. Crashing soon");
        }
    }

    *e = env;
}
```

When stepped through you see that the call to (*vm)->GetEnv segfaults:

```
jni_get_long (ctx=0x40525080, key=0x804215e0 "hm") at jni/jni.c:50
50      GET_JNI_ENV(&env);
(gdb) s
get_jni_env (e=0xbec603e8) at jni/../../../../core/android/util.c:159
159     if((*vm)->GetEnv(vm, (void **)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_4) != JNI_OK) {
(gdb) n
156 void get_jni_env(void **e) {
(gdb) 
157     JNIEnv *env = malloc(sizeof(JNIEnv *));
(gdb) 
159     if((*vm)->GetEnv(vm, (void **)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_4) != JNI_OK) {
(gdb) 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xaca43510 in ?? ()  ← this is somewhere on the heap
```

The same code works perfectly fine on Samsung and Sony Ericsson devices as well as in the emulator. I'm somewhat out of ideas for this particular error. I also tested an HTC device with CyanogenMod 7.1 which should be fairly similar to the AOSP android and even there it crashes at the same point.

Answer (score 2):

Can't understand, why do you mallocate your JNIEnv variable? Android does it for you. Anyway, here is my code, which works greatly on my HTC Desire:

```
JNIEnv *GetJEnv() {
  JNIEnv *res;
  if (jvm->GetEnv((void **)&res,JNI_VERSION_1_6)==JNI_EDETACHED)
    jvm->AttachCurrentThread(&res,NULL);
  return res;
}
```

Comment: Well that can be ignored. I tried to find out if it was caused by some faulty addresses on the stack and moved the address with malloc() to the heap. But the issue seems to be somewhere else. Your version won't work either, I already tried it beforehand. But thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

`JNIEnv *env = malloc(sizeof(JNIEnv *));`

is *wrong*.

It allocates memory that can hold a *pointer* to a `JNIEnv` object, not the amount memory for a `JNIEnv` object itself.

It should be

```
JNIEnv *env = malloc(sizeof(JNIEnv));
```

or even better:

```
JNIEnv *env = malloc(sizeof( *env ));
```

"Works perfectly fine" on other platforms doesn't mean it's correct.